# Tika in Action book examples Lucene StandardAnalyzer does not work

Tags: java, lucene, apache-tika

First of all I am a total noob when it comes to Tika and Lucene. I am working through the Tika in Action book trying out the examples. In chapter 5 this example is given:

```
package tikatest01;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Index;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;

public class LuceneIndexer {

    private final Tika tika;
    private final IndexWriter writer;

    public LuceneIndexer(Tika tika, IndexWriter writer) {
        this.tika = tika;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void indexDocument(File file) throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field(
            "filename", file.getName(),
            Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field(
            "fulltext", tika.parseToString(file),
            Store.NO, Index.ANALYZED));
        writer.addDocument(document);
    }
}
```

And this main method:

```
package tikatest01;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

public class TikaTest01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename = "C:\\testdoc.pdf";
        File file = new File(filename);

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(
            new SimpleFSDirectory(file),
            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), 
            MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        try {
            LuceneIndexer indexer = new LuceneIndexer(new Tika(), writer);
            indexer.indexDocument(file);
            } 
        finally {
            writer.close();
            }
    }
}
```

I've added the libraries tika-app-1.5.jar, lucene-core-4.7.0.jar and lucene-analyzers-common-4.7.0.jar to the project.

Questions:

With the current version of Lucene the Field.Index is deprecated, what should I use instead?

MaxFieldLength is not found. I am missing an import?

Comment: Use Lucene 3.6 or learn all these API's more comprehensively.

Comment: Learning the API's more comprehensively is exactly why I am reading the books. However, everything seems to be written on Lucene 3.x, not 4.x :S

Comment: Okay. Got the answer partly to my second question. I need to add the lucene-analyzers-common-4.7.0.jar to my project and import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer MaxFieldLength problem still persists. Updated the question for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Lucene 4.7 this code for the indexer:

```
package tikatest01;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

public class LuceneIndexer {

    private final Tika tika;
    private final IndexWriter writer;

    public LuceneIndexer(Tika tika, IndexWriter writer) {
        this.tika = tika;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void indexDocument(File file) throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new TextField(
                "filename", file.getName(), Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField(
                "fulltext", tika.parseToString(file), Store.NO));
        writer.addDocument(document);
    }
}
```

And this code for the main class:

```
package tikatest01;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

public class TikaTest01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String dirname = "C:\\MyTestDir\\";
        File dir = new File(dirname);


        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(
            new SimpleFSDirectory(dir), 
            new IndexWriterConfig(
                Version.LUCENE_47, 
                new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47)));
        try {
            LuceneIndexer indexer = new LuceneIndexer(new Tika(), writer);
            indexer.indexDocument(dir);
            } 
        finally {
            writer.close();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Lucene 4.7 there isn't this kind of constructor for IndexWriter
Take a look on API - http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html

It show me only constructor with 2 params, so you need to adopt this example to new Lucene API