# How to develop a simple search engine for full text search in local files

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Could someone tell me from where I have to start to develop a simple full text search engine for local files?

I have a Debian 7 server with LAMP and I have mounted a windows network drive on it. So far I am using [this script](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script) to show the other local network users the directory tree where they can download files from the mounted network drive.

But I have to build a simple search engine which could index the names and the content (if any) of local files in the mounted folder - Microsoft doc, docx, xls, xlsx, rtf, txt. The search has to return the name of the file, the path and the best would be if there is a part of the text where the search word(s) present (if the file has text).

Could someone point me to the right direction what I have to read and learn to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a couple of tools for this.  You need something to index and search content, and you've tagged the question with three good tools for this task, [lucene](/questions/tagged/lucene), [solr](/questions/tagged/solr), and [[image]elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch).  Each one of them is rich with tutorials and examples to help you get started.

The other thing you will need, is a way to *read* the content from all those different file types.  I'd recommend [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/).  It's an excellent toolkit for this, reads all the formats you've listed, and works well with Lucene.

You can see an example of their use together in this question : [Tika in Action book examples Lucene StandardAnalyzer does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744277/tika-in-action-book-examples-lucene-standardanalyzer-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks I will look the documentation. Do you have experience with elasticsearch?

Comment: I am just wonderring if you get me some comparizon between these solutions behalf of your experience.

Comment: Lucene is a search library, Solr and Elasticsearch are ready-to-use search servers, both of which are built on Lucene.  As far as a comparison between Solr and Elasticsearch: no, not interested in providing comparisons.  They are both excellent products.  Do some research, and pick the one that suits you better.  [The sematext blog provided an in-depth comparison](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/23/solr-vs-elasticsearch-part-1-overview/), though in the intervening year and a half both have been in *very* active development, including a major version jump for ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this helpful, you may not.

I have Solr and Nutch set up to index my local filesystem and store them in Solr and have guides on how I set them up that way.

This would provide a solid backend for your application.

Here are the links. First two for Solr set up, last two for Nutch integration

http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html
http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-tika-extracting-request.html

http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html
http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-nutch-to-crawl-filesystem.html

Comment: Thanks I will check your guides even they are for windows setup.

Comment: Linux settings shouldnt be too different